# Related to the oops concepts

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am having a very basic question  that can even annoy you but that comes in my mind when In started reading the Visual c# e-book.

They have mentioned that::
Surprisingly, the Circle class is currently of no practical use. By default, when you encapsulate your methods and data inside a class, the class forms a boundary to the outside world. Fields (such as radius) and methods (such as Area) defined in the class can be seen by other methods inside the class but not by the outside world—they are private to the class. So, although you can create a Circle object in a program, you cannot access its radius field or call its Area method, which is why the class is not of much use—yet! However, you can modify the definition of a field or method with the public

and this is Circle class given

```
class Circle
{
    int radius;

    double Area()
    {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

So, Private fields are not accessible but when I tried something like this in my Console project , I am running it successfully. Is it that we have main function in the class and that's why I can get my private fields accesed by the object of Program class?

```
class Program 
    {

      int number;
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program ObjProgram = new Program();
            ObjProgram.number = 10;
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access private fields from within the same class - *any* instance of the class can access the private fields of *any* other instance.

So you can create a `Program` and access its private fields from within `Program.Main`.

If you tried it from a method in another class, it wouldn't work.

```
class Program 
{
   int number;

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Program ObjProgram = new Program();
        ObjProgram.number = 10;                // works fine
        Console.ReadLine();
   }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
   void SomeMethod()
   {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.number = 10;                  // does not compile!
   }
}
```

Comment: I've added an example - is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Because `number` is in the Program class too.

Answer (score 1):

Main method is member of Program class

hence it(main) can access Private members of Program Class ...

for example

```
class a
{
    int x;
    void somemethod1()
    {
        x=10;  //this will work fine 
    }
}
class b
{
    int y;
    void somemethod2()
    {
       a a1=new a();
       a1.x=10; //this wont work because a1.x is private ... can only be accessible my members of class a
    }

}
```